# Why is there no mention of the distinction between teshuva me'ahava and teshuva me'yira in the Rambam's hilchos teshuva?

Tags: rambam, repentance-teshuvah

In all 10 chapters of the Rambam's hilchos teshuva, there is no mention of teshuva me'ahava or teshuv me'yira, why is that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What about chapter 10?

Comment: @Deuteronomy What about it? He does not mention teshuva me'ahava or me'yirah in chapter 10. He does talk about ahavas Hashem, but that doesn't answer my question unless I misunderstood you...

Comment: Is teshubha not 'abhodah? He clearly discusses 'abbhodah meahabhah/meyirah, with the context being the first few halakhoth in the ultimate chapter of Teshubhah. Clearly he understands this to be an aspect of teshubhah. Are you just looking for that exact phrasing?